# Algebraic manipulation and logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can i manipulate $3\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)^{\log_2 3}$ to equal $n^{\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}}$? I understand that $$\log_b a = \dfrac{\log_2 a}{log_2 b}$$ but i'm not sure how the $3/2$ went away.

Comment: $3*\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\log_2 3}=3*\left(\frac{n^{\log_2 3}}{2^{\log_2 3}}\right)=3*\left(\frac{n^{\log_2 3}}{3}\right)=n^{\log_2 3}$

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Use $n^{Log_a b} = n^{Log[b]/Log[a]}$.